# Docker compose Spring Boot + Neo4j

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, neo4j, dockerfile

I have a docker file where I clone my git repository, create the jar and run.

```
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git maven
RUN git clone <git_url> /app/socialB
WORKDIR /app/socialB
RUN mvn package
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/target/socialB.jar"]
```

I use this DockerFile in a docker compose.

```
version: '3'
services:
  neo4j:
    image: neo4j:4.3.6
    container_name: neo4j
    ports:
      - "7474:7474"
      - "7687:7687"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
    environment:
      - NEO4J_AUTH=neo4j/password
  spring-boot:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerFile
    container_name: spring-boot
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - DB_URL=neo4j
      - DB_PORT=7687
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=neo4j
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=password
    depends_on:
      - neo4j
```

Both files are in the same folder.

Neo4j image works correctly, but Spring Boot gives the following error:

```
spring-boot  | Error: Unable to access jarfile /target/socialB.jar
spring-boot exited with code 1
```

Instead of using I have also used:

```
RUN ./mvnw package
```

perfectly creating the target folder.

Change paths from /target/socialB.jar to /app/SocialB/target/socialB.jar .

On local everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to launch your app from `/target/socialB.jar` but you put your repository content in `/app/socialB` then package the application from there so your jar file will ultimately be located at `/app/socialB/target/socialB.jar`

Try to change the last line in your Dockerfile to

```
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app/socialB/target/socialB.jar"]
```